# Is there a data structure that allows an object property to be accessed with two keys in either order?

Tags: data-structures

Let's say, for sake of an arbitrary example, that I want to store information about twinned towns. I want to be able to access the data about the twinning by having the names of both towns as keys, but assuming that neither is the 'initial' key. So I'd access the data property like this: `twinning_data['derby', 'montreal'] = { 'year': 1986 }` or in reverse: `twinning_data[ 'montreal', 'derby'] = { 'year': 1986 }`.

The best I can come up with is just to concatenate the strings and then try one and then the other way round. Perhaps there is an order independent hash one could use?

Comment: If such data structure already exists will depend on the language that you are using. You might want to add a tag for that.

Comment: You could just sort the two key items alphabetically before you use your keys for lookups or inserts

Comment: @tiguchi - that makes perfect sense, can't believe I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add them together character by character or perform any other commutative operation, then hash the result.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a normal `Map` with a `Bag<City>` or a `Set<City>` as keys. `Map`s, `Set`s, and to a lesser extent `Bag`s are usually available in any decent collections / data structures library.

Here's an example in Ruby:

```ruby
require 'set'

twinning_data = { Set['derby', 'montreal'] => { year: 1986 } }
twinning_data[Set['montreal', 'derby']]
#=> { :year => 1986 }
```

Of course, `Bag`s and `Set`s can technically have an arbitrary number of elements, whereas you want to have exactly 2; ergo, the type is not particularly precise. A more precise type would be some sort of `BinaryUndirectedRelation` type, which however, probably doesn't readily exist outside of a graph library or the internals of an RDBMS kernel.

Comment: defining the `BinaryUndirectedRelation` yourself is fairly easy, just take two elements at construction and store them sorted.